# Is there a way to create an R matrix (datatype) in PowerBI?

Tags: r, powerbi

I was trying to create a table in PowerBI using the R script (matrix datatype).

```
dt <- matrix(c(12,2,7,9), 2, 2)

dimnames(dt) <- list(Diarrhea = c("Yes", "No"),
                       "Antibody level" = c("Low", "High")
)
```

Unfortunately, PowerBI isn't able to identify the matrix datatype to load the table. 
[image]

Any workarounds to achieve this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the matrix in a serialized format that can be read by Power BI:

---

**csv**

```r
write.csv(dt, "powerbi.csv")
```

---

**json**

```
writeLines(jsonlite::toJSON(dt), "powerbi.json")
```

or

```
writeLines(jsonlite::serializeJSON(dt), "powerbi.json")
```

Comment: When I import it back to PowerBI, the row names are interpreted as a new column. That doesn't help in my use-case.